# Symfony2 + Twig: Translate label into a new twig extension

Tags: symfony, translation, twig

I have implemented a new twig extension and I have some text which had to be translated.

Unfortunately when I use a `code label` it appears as a sample text.

I mean when twig render this following extension, it displays: **`5 entity.years`** instead of **`5 years`** for example:

```
class MyExtension extends \Twig_Extension {
public function getFilters()
{
    return array(
        'myextension' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'myextension'),
    );
}

public function myextension ($myId)
{
        // ....
        // Some operations concerning $myId...
        // ....
    if($myId!=0) { 
        $res = $myId. ' '.'entity.year'; 
    } else { 
        $res = ($months == 0 ? $days.'entity.days' : $months.'entity.months'); 
    } 

    return $res;
}
}
```

Where `entity.years`, `entity.months`, `entity.days` is defined into my translations folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Inject](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services) the `translator` service into your extension and use it. For example:

```php
class MyExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    private $translator;

    public function __construct(Translator $translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    // ...

    public function myMethod()
    {
        return $this->translator->trans('my_string');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I have error: Argument 1 passed to MySpace\MyBundle\Extension\MyExtension::__construct() must be an instance of Translator, none given, in ’app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php’

Comment: Seems like you forgot the [dependency injection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services) part.

Comment: May I add into my service:
         arguments: 
            -  translation.loader
like this?

Comment: how doI add translator argument?

Comment: If you haven't already, you should read the [Service Container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) chapter to understand the dependency injection approach.

Comment: I have read this chapter but I haven't found the way I have to add the translator argument into my service...

Comment: The translator service should be called 'translator'. And it would be better to type hint TranslatorInterface instead of Translator in the construcor param

Comment: In fact, Interface injection may have been deleted in symfony2, so forget about that.